# Duplicate values in R with differents data.frames

Tags: r

I'm testing an code that I may be abble to use in my job. I simulated fewer values and create this data.frame:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPnjI.png

Now, I need to delete the rows where are similar chassis from another Data.Frame

For ex:

```
A <- data.frame(HBZN350NHJ1245780,HBZN350NHJ1245601,HBZN350NHJ1245699)
```

This chassis are similar to the ones in the rows 6,4 and 2. I need this rows to be deleted in that fist data.frame, is there an way?

*I will use it to treat an massive database, with this code I will be able dealing with the operational part much faster

*The data.frame A that I use as an exemple is in a excel file, I imported it in R

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We may use `subset`

```
subset(df1, !Chassi %in% A[[1]])
```

Or if it needs to be faster, use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = 'Chassi')
df2 <- df1[!A[[1]]]
```